# In C is it ok to use & and [] together to quickly get the pointer to an object in an array?

Tags: c, performance

I know this works to get the index (and do the pointer arithmetic automatically):

`struct Obj *c = &p[i];`

However, does this have a performance hit compared to doing the pointer arithmetic manually?

`struct Obj *c = p+i;`

Are there any reasons why the first should be avoided?

Comment: On any decent compiler, not really.

Comment: I would say a good compiler should generate equally efficient  code.

Comment: The second should be `struct Obj *c = p+i;` which is the very same as the first one.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Ok thanks, I corrected it.

Comment: Well, after the edit the question is trivial. C standard is defining both expressions equivalent. They are syntactical sugar of each other.

Comment: Ok, well I thought the first would be the same as `struct Obj *c = &(*(p+i))` and it seems obvious that a compiler would optimize that out, but just wanted to confirm it was a recommended pattern for c.

Comment: To clarify, before the edit... the question had a problem with pointer arithmetic (for non-1 sized objects)

Comment: That's standard way to get a pointer to an element. In fact, remember that arrays naturally decays to pointers to their first element, which means for an array `a` using plain `a` is exactly the same as doing `&a[0]`.

Comment: Also, for any pointer or array `p` and index `i`, the expression `p[i]` is *exactly* equal to `*(p + i)`. That's part of the C standard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> However, does this have a performance hit compared to doing the pointer arithmetic manually?

Expressions using the indexing operator are *defined* to be equivalent to corresponding operations involving pointer arithmetic and dereferencing, so

```
&p[i]
```

is exactly equivalent to

```
&(*(p + i))
```

The standard furthermore specifies that when the operand of the `&` operator is the result of a `*` operator, neither is evaluated, and the result is as if both were omitted, so that is in turn equivalent to

```
p + i
```

, which has defined behavior as long as it does not purport to produce a pointer to before the beginning of the array from which pointer `p` was derived, nor more than one position past its end.

Although it is conceivable that a compiler would produce different or worse code in one case than in the other, there is no reason to expect that.

> Are there any reasons why the first should be avoided?

Not much.  The latter has a lighter cognitive load and is easier to read, inasmuch as (syntactically) it involves only one operation rather than two.  I tend to prefer it myself for that reason.  On the other hand, *understanding* it may be a little less intuitive.

Comment: I think the second one is UB for the same `i` as `*(p+i)` is UB in that case.

Comment: I thought there was a special rule in the standard that `&*p` is exactly equivalent to `p`.

Comment: Is it correct to call pointing past the end of an array undefined behavior? The compiler doesn't know anything about array length. It is simply that the reference will be pointing past the end of the array (which is a valid address like any, just not valid data).

Comment: The same rule applies to the `[]` notation. *Thus, &*E is equivalent to E (even if E is a null pointer), **and &(E1[E2]) to ((E1)+(E2))**.* - http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note102 So there is no difference at all.

Comment: @EugeneSh., it is explicitly allowed to compute a pointer to one past the last element of an array via pointer addition, and also explicitly specified that attempting to dereference such a result produces UB.  See paragraph [6.5.6/8](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.6p8) of the standard.

Comment: @JohnBollinger ...and `*(p+i)` is dereferencing.

Comment: @JohnBollinger thank you for the reference to the specification. That helps!

Comment: @user3386109, you are correct, and I have updated this answer accordingly.  I suspect, in fact, that that special rule is exactly intended for this case.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: But `&*(p+i)` is NOT dereferencing.  (In C.  The rules are more complicated in C++, and still being revised for clarity)

Comment: @EugeneSh. yes, `*(p+i)` is dereferencing, and I specified that the equivalence to the following is provisional on `i` being less than the number of array elements.  However, as user3386109 observed, there is also an explicit special provision that when `&` is applied to the result of an `*` operator, *neither is evaluated*, and it is as if both were omitted.  This is in [paragraph 6.5.3.2/3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.2p3) of the standard.

Comment: The two forms are equivalent for *all* values of `i`, including negative or larger than the array size.  (If the pointer arithmetic doesn't yield the address of an element within the same array that `p` points into, then the result of both forms is undefined behavior)

Comment: @BenVoigt, John - That is debatable. It is dereferencing (or not-dereferencing) in the same sense as `&p[i]` as the rule applies for both notations as I cited above. Anyway, Annex J.2 is explicitly stating that the operand of unary `*` has to be valid without exception. Also the rule is subject to constraint in 6.5.3.2p1 which is *The operand of the unary & operator shall be either a function designator, the **result of a [] or unary * operator***. So applying it to a bad `i` is a constraint violation.

Comment: @EugeneSh: No constraints on values apply to unevaluated expressions.  For example `sizeof ((T*)0)->member` is permitted even though it has the form of a dereference of a null pointer.  The dereference is not performed.  Same with `&*(p + i)`.  No dereference is performed, although it is syntactically present..

Comment: @BenVoigt Constraints in the standard apply not to expressions but serve as a prerequisites for the correctness of the stated semantics. The rules you are stating are coming from the semantics section which is not valid while the constraints are violated.

Comment: @EugeneSh: Here's the rule that makes unevaluated expressions allowed irrespective of constraints: ["Expressions that are not evaluated do not access objects"](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.1p4)

Comment: @EugeneSh., Annex J is non-normative.  As for constraints, in `&*(p + i)`, the operand of the `&` operator is absolutely, without doubt, the result of a unary `*` operation.  Whether *evaluating* that operation would have defined behavior is not relevant to that analysis, and that would be exactly the point of the Standard calling out explicitly that in this special case, neither the `&` nor the `*` is evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

That second version is perplexing and stands out as an anomaly, so unless you have an extremely compelling case for using it, don't. If you *do*, then you should document why so someone doesn't go and replace it with the former.

The second form is also really brittle in that it might break if you changed something by refactoring and introducing a new struct like:

```
struct Mobj *c = p + i * sizeof(struct Obj);
```

Where you forgot to update the `sizeof` part and now your code is super broken.

That of course overlooks the fact that when doing pointer math it will automatically increment by the size of the structure anyway, that is:

```
p[i] == *(p + i)
```

But in your case what you're doing is effectively this:

```
p[i * sizeof(Obj)]
```

Which is not what you're intending.

Less is more. Coding is hard enough as it is, don't overcomplicate things.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @tadman. I did not know that doing pointer arithmetic would consider the size (though it was not the intent of my original question).

Answer (score 2):

Yea, it is okay. In fact, when you use p it is actually the same as &p[0] from the compiler's point of view. Always let the compiler do the pointer math for you, use the first form.

Answer (score 0):

The C standard states that `&array[index]` is exactly equivalent to `array + index`.  This means that both do pointer arithmetic, so they should be no different.

Even if they were different choosing one over the other would be a microoptimization that's not worth doing unless you have a significant measurable difference between them.

Comment: @BenVoigt this is what I would consider the answer.

Comment: @RickLove: John has now captured all the nuances correctly in his answer, IMO.  Also I saw where the C standard does (redundantly) make the statement dbush talks about, so my earlier comment was wrong.